# Laravel Notifiable - Send notification to onl specific user id

Tags: laravel

I was able to send notifications to all `users` who are admin, but now I just wanted to send a specific notification to a single user using it's `id`.

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    $employeeObjective = EmployeeObjective::updateOrCreate(
      [ 'employee_id' => $request->employee_id ?? null ],
      [
        'employee_id' => $request->employee_id,
        'rater_id_1' => $request->rater_id_1,
        'status' => 'Pending',
      ]
    );

    // Working to send all admins
    $admins = User::all()->filter(function($user) {
      return $user->hasRole('Admin');
    });
    Notification::send($admins, new UserRegistered($employeeObjective));

    // Not working
    User::where('employee_id', $request->rater_id_1)->notify(new UserRegistered($employeeObjective));
 }
```

Comment: How many admin are there?

Comment: There are two admin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the `notify` method on an instance which owns it, `User::where('employee_id', $request->rater_id_1)` returns an `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder` instance which you can't use `notify` on.

```php
User::where('employee_id', $request->rater_id_1)
    ->firstOrFail()
    ->notify(new UserRegistered($employeeObjective));
```